# ASP.NET Core pass data from AJAX to View

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I am new to ASP.NET and I am trying to pass a JSON object via AJAX to a view where the object can be modified. I have a button with a click event that uses a POST method to send the data to an Action method that deserializes the string into an object and redirects that object to another Action method that renders the View. The AJAX success function completes successfully and I can see the View in the Network tab of Developer Tools but in the UI the button appears to be doing nothing at all. I am not familiar with routing in ASP.NET and am wondering if there is a routing issue in my Controller.

**AJAX**

```
function myFunc(){
     
    $("#myTable").unbind().on('click','.stageBtn',function(){
     // get the current row
     var currentRow = $(this).closest("tr")[0]; 
     var cells = currentRow.cells;

    var dataObject = JSON.stringify({
    'serial': cells[2].textContent,
    'sku': cells[3].textContent,
    'make': cells[0].textContent,
    'model': cells[1].textContent,
    'quantity': cells[4].textContent,
    'description': cells[5].textContent,
    'location': cells[6].textContent,

        });

        $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'Home/Stage',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify(dataObject),
    success:function() {
       alert("Success");
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("Fail");
    }
});
   
     event.stopPropagation? event.stopPropagation() : event.cancelBubble = true;
     return false;
    });
   
    return false;
 }
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Stage([FromBody]string p) {

            Product product = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Product>(p);
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest("Enter required fields.");
            }
            else {
                return RedirectToAction("Detail",product.ToStaging());
            }
           
        }

       
        public IActionResult Detail(Staging s)
        {
            return View(s);
        }
```

The Request URL is of the format: localhost/Home/Detail?{serial}&{sku}&{make}&{model}&{quantity}&{description}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so you are using `AJAX` which is used to update a portion of the page without reloading the entire page or do a redirection based on the result that you get back from your server.

Now, you are trying to redirect from the `Controller` itself which is incorrect because that is not how `AJAX` works. You would need to send back a result to you `View` from your `AJAX` call and then do the redirection

In your case, you can do this:

You need to return a `JSON` result from your `Controller`. Now since you want to also send your `Model`, you can store it in a `Session` variable and access it after the redirect from the `AJAX` call:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Stage([FromBody]string p) 
{

    Product product = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Product>(p);
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
         return Json(new {status="false", msg= "Enter required fields."});
    }
    else {
        Session["myModel"] = product.ToStaging();
        return Json(new {status="true", msg= "Redirect now"});
    }      
}
```

And your `AJAX` call will be:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    //url: 'Home/Stage',
    url: '@Url.Action("Stage", "Home")',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify(dataObject),
    success:function(data) {
      if(data.status=="true")
      {
        var urlToRedirect= '@Url.Action("Detail","Home")';
        window.location.href = urlToRedirect; //Redirect here
      }
      else
      {
        alert(data.msg)
      }
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("Fail");
    }
});
```

And you can retrieve your `Model` in your `Detail` method like this:

```
public IActionResult Detail()
{
   Staging myModel = new Staging();
   if(Session["myModel"] != null)
   {
      //Cast your session variable as required
      myModel  = (Staging)(Session["myModel"]);
   }
   return View(myModel);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This link was helpful: https://www.talkingdotnet.com/store-complex-objects-in-asp-net-core-session